# Type error from numpy FFT function

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data that I measure and am trying to get the fft of the data to figure out the correct cut off frequency for a low pass filter. However, when I use the fft function provided by numpy I end up with the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fom7I.jpg)

The code that is used is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
import fyp_lib

file = raw_input('file name: ')

cur_file = open( 'data/' + file + '.txt', 'r' )
data = fyp_lib.parse_data( cur_file )
data = np.array(data)

np.fft.rfft(data)
```

It just reads in data from a .txt file, parses out the information into a dict and the converts it to a np array. If someone could please help me solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at what's in `data`.

Comment: data is just a dictionary of floats

Comment: I can show the full code that is used to parse the data out of that helps

Comment: You can't pass a dict of floats into an numpy array. You need a list or something